# conditional width and preventDefault

Tags: jquery, width, conditional-statements

I have div that makes something by default and makes something else if it has a specific width. 
I think I have the problem in the conditional. How can I say: "if you have width 150px do something but do not do anything else" What is wrong with my code?

Here is the example to play [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/w25mQ/)

jQUERY:

```
   $(function(){
        $('#menu').click(function(event) {
        if ('#menu'.width() === 150){
        event.preventDefault();
            alert("something");         
        }
        }); 

        $("#menu").click(function() {
        $("this").animate({right: 0}, 500);
        });     
    })
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px; right:50px;
    width:150px; height:108px;
    background:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu"> </div>
```

Comment: What is that: `'#menu'.width()`??? You need to wrap string selector inside jquery object, i mean: `$('#menu').width()` and this is wrong too: `$("this")` and you should use only one click handler, and etc... SO is not a debugging service, open your console and when really stuck, ask relevant question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a change to your syntax - http://jsfiddle.net/w25mQ/4/

```
if( $('#menu').width === 150 )....
```

and

```
$(this).animate....
```

The commenter is right though, you should combine your click handlers, like this - http://jsfiddle.net/w25mQ/5/

Comment: Thank you, your corrections are good. To avoid the div "do anything else" I have added and else statement here: http://jsfiddle.net/w25mQ/7/

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of misuse with jQuery in your code :

```
$(function(){
    $('#menu').on('click', function(event) {
        if ($(this).width() === 150){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("something");         
        }
    }); 

    $("#menu").on('click', function() {
        $(this).animate({right: 0}, 500);
    });
})
```

Here is your corrected code and the example to play with it [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rockstarn1/Qg7wy/)